# Jquery .width() returns 0

Tags: jquery, width

When I try to get the width of an element with ID #content it just returns 0

Strangely enough on JSFiddle it seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/4urJT/5/

```
 //<![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function () {
            /*alert($('#container').width()); */
            var columnCount = 4;
            var gutter = 15;

            $('.post').width(function() {
                var calculatedColumnWidth = (((($('#content').width() - ((columnCount*gutter) - gutter)) / columnCount) / $('#content').width()) * 100)+'%';

                return calculatedColumnWidth;
            });

            $( window ).resize(function() {
                $('.post').width(function() {
                    var calculatedColumnWidth = (((($('#content').width() - ((columnCount*gutter) - gutter)) / columnCount) / $('#content').width()) * 100)+'%';
                    return calculatedColumnWidth;
                });
            });

            var container = $('#content');

            container.masonry({

                itemSelector: '.post',
                gutter: gutter,

            });     
        });
        //]]>
```

Comment: Have you looked for a difference, for example in doctype or jQuery version?

Comment: can you give sample of your html and css ?

Comment: Try `console.log($('#container'))` and see if you are actually finding an element.

Comment: Both doctypes and jQuery versions are the same. Here's the link to my project: http://aqua-shake.tumblr.com ; The console returns the following: n.fn.init[0] context: document selector: "#content" __proto__: Object[0] you can check it on the link above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. I had a CSS class .post left over that had padding 10px and border 1px and somehow was adding 800+px to the #content div. Problem solved.